# Best way to instantiate different object types according to value?

Tags: c++

I'll simplify my problem of hundreds of classes to a count of two and try to explain what I mean:

```
class Base {
};
class A: public Base {
};
class B: public Base{
};

static Base* foo (int bar){

    switch (bar) {
        case 0:
            return new A();
            break;              
        case 1:
            return new B();
            break;
        default:
            return new Base();
    }
}
```

I want to instantiate objects according to the value of bar. I just feel switch-case isn't the best way in C++ to do so for way more inheritors of `Base` .

Edit: going with the `std::map` approach I came up with this:

```
struct Dictionary {
    typedef Base* (Dictionary::*FunctionPointer)(void);
    std::map <int, FunctionPointer> fmap;

    Dictionary() {
        fmap.insert(std::make_pair(0, new A()));
        fmap.insert(std::make_pair(1, new B()));
    }

    Base* Call (const int i){
        FunctionPointer fp = NULL;
        fp = fmap[i];
        if (fp){
            return (this->*fp)();
        } else {
            return new Base();
        }
    }
};

static Dictionary dictionary;
```

Comment: It is OK, but you probably want to return `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: That's the way to do it. This is commonly known as the factory pattern.

Comment: Have you tried an array of function pointers?

Comment: @EugenRieck why would that be better?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore 1. it is easier to maintain, 2. it can be dynamically modified ... say "plugin infrastructure"

Comment: One of the acceptable places to have a switch is in a factory. Alternatively you could use a `map` between a `string` and [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) objects.

Comment: @juanchopanza What makes you think he wants to return a `std::unique_ptr`?  He hasn't said anything to indicate that the objects aren't fully initialized in the constructor, and that the caller must do some additional initialization.

Comment: @PeterWood Or even better, a map between a `string` (or `unsigned int`) and a constructor `std::function`.

Comment: @JamesKanze it makes the ownership explicit and deals with de-allocation. I wasn't considering any initialization issues.

Comment: @juanchopanza If the object is dynamically allocated, the "ownership" (whatever that means) should be explicit to begin with.  And in most cases, `std::unique_ptr` will deal with deallocation incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot depends on the circumstances, but the most frequent
solution is probably to use a static instance of a map to
factory functions.  If the key type of the map is a small
integer value, as in your example, the "map" can be nothing more
than a C style array:

```
static Base*
foo( int bar )
{
    static Base* (*factories[])() = [ &aFactory, &bFactory ];
    return bar >= 0 && bar < size( factories )
        ? (*factories[bar])()
        : baseFactory();
}
```

More generally, you can use an `std::map` (to discriminate on
any imaginable type), and you can map to static instances of
factory objects, rather than factory functions, if different
keys should result in the same type, but with different
arguments.

### EDIT:

Some suggestions to improve your `Dictionary::Call` function:

```
Base* Dictionary::Call( int i ) const
{
    std::map<int, FunctionPointer>::const_iterator
                        entry = fmap.find( i );
    return entry == fmap.end()
        ? new Base()
        : (this->*(entry->second))();
}
```

I've made the function `const`, since it doesn't modify
anything, and most impprtantly, I use `std::map<>::find`, to
avoid inserting extra entries into the map if the object isn't
already there.

And since I'm adding the const, you'll have to update the
typedef:

```
typedef Base* (Dictionary::*FunctionPointer)() const;
```

Another suggestion: unless the factory functions need access
`Dictionary`, make them static.  The syntax is a lot simpler
(and it will probably also improve performance).
static changes the typedef again:

Also: in the constructor, `new A()` is *not* a function
constructing a new object.  There may be something to
facilitate this in C++11 (between lambda and `std::function`),
but otherwise, you'll still have to write each of the factory
functions by hand.  Or you could use a template:

```
template <typename Target>
Base* construct() const
{
    return new Target();
}

Dictionary()
{
    fmap.insert( std::make_pair( 0, &Dictionary::construct<A> ) );
    //  ...
}
```

Or if you make them static:

```
typedef Base* (*FunctionPointer)();

//  ...
template <typename Target>
static Base* construct()
{
    return new Target();
}

Base* Dictionary::Call( int i ) const
{
    std::map<int, FunctionPointer>::const_iterator
                        entry = fmap.find( i );
    return entry == fmap.end()
        ? new Base()
        : (*entry->second)();
}
```

You'll notice how the static simplifies the declarations (and
the function call through the pointer—your pointer to
member function has become a simple pointer to function).

Comment: thank you for your answer. since i have ~250 function calls, i took your `std::map` approach and came up with the edit. happy for any suggestions.

Comment: @dos One suggestion: I'd use `std::map<>::find` to do the lookup, rather than `std::map<>::operator[]`.  The second will insert new entries into the map (with a null pointer) if it doesn't find one; the first won't.  I've edited to add some further suggestions.

Comment: making the `Call` function `const` results in a "Call to pointer member function of type 'Base *()' drops 'const' qualifier". Using a template for the constructor functions results in a 'semantic issue' : "In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::pair<const int, Base *(Dictionary::*)()>::pair<int, Base *(*)()>' requested here"

Comment: @dos Yes.  You'll have to propagate it everywhere: in the typedef and in the template function.

Comment: would you mind editing your post accordingly? I'm a little helpless regarding the template calls. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: @dos Done.  There was actually an error in my earlier version: I'd started by just making things const, then I thought I'd add the static.  Without changing the other things which needed changing.  I'd use the static functions if possible.

Comment: thanks. again :) at the moment I'm trying to put static convenience constructor into the `Base` class and pass some parameters in that call. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @dos Replace the factory functions with functional objects.  I usually do this anyway, because sooner or later, I'll need the extra arguments.  Define a base class with a pure virtual function, then any derived classes you might need (perhaps using templates for some of them).  Create an instance with static lifetime of a derived classes for each type to be constructed, and map to a pointer to those instances.